# How to handle multiple websocket subscriptions in React?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux-saga

I subscribe to several symbols such as BTC-USD and EUR-USD using the websocket API.
The response comes in the form of a constant flow of objects (such as {symbol: 'EUR-USD', price: '1.1'}) mixed in the flow of messages: some with the price for EUR-USD and some with the price for BTC-USD.

I'd like to display the values in a table. How can I do that ?

I thought of something as follows (it doesn't work) :

```
this.socket.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  e.data.symbol === 'EUR-USD' && this.setState({ pairEURUSD: JSON.parse(e.data) });
  e.data.symbol === 'BTC-USD' && this.setState({ pairBTCUSD: JSON.parse(e.data) });
});
```

Then in the render method show the appropriate state pair.

I also thought of the following in the render method (it kind of works) :

```
<p>{this.state.pair === 'BTC-USD' && this.state.pair.price}</p>
<p>{this.state.pair === 'EUR-USD' && this.state.pair.price}</p>
```

This renders nothing for EUR-USD if the latest output message is for the BTC-USD pair. I would obviously like to render something, the latest value, while one pair has no updated value.

Any suggestion how to implement in a function or class component or (probably even better) with redux-saga  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much code to go on, but I think you have the right idea. You just probably have a mistake in how you are reading/writing the state.

If you want to use sagas, you will first need the `eventChannel` utility to wrap the listener.

```js
import {eventChannel} from 'redux-saga'

const socketChannel = eventChannel((emit) => {
  socket.addEventListener('message', emit)
  return () => socket.removeEventListener('message', emit)
})
```

Then you can use the `take` effects on this channel the same way as you would for redux actions:

```js
yield takeEvery(socketChannel, function* (message) {
  const {symbol, price} = JSON.parse(message.data)
  yield put(storeNewValue(symbol, price))
})
```

After that its just your normal react/reducer logic to read/write the data, so e.g.

```js
// reducer
...
case STORE_NEW_VALUE:
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.symbol]: action.price,
  }
...
```

```js
// react
const ItemTable = () => {
  const data = useSelector(state => state.path.to.data)
  const rows = Object.entries(data).map(([symbol, price]) => (
    <div>{symbol + ' ' + price}</div>
  ))
  return <div>{rows}</div>
}
```

Check out working demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dt8us?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks so much Martin ! Your reply helped. I had to adapt it to my case though. But it seems it causes a very high CPU load. Is it due to handling real time ? Is it due to the frequency of incoming data, therefore to the high refreshing frequency ? How to mitigate the impact on CPU load ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Do you get the highcpu even with the codesandbox I sent or only with your modified solution in your own project? As far as I can tell, there isn't anything in the code I wrote that should cause high cpu unless you receive thousands of messages every second.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Your codesandbox sample doesn't generate high cpu load, but using real data, rather than simulated real time, in my case, causes high cpu load.